# Background Wing Sections Fixed after Scroll

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I’m working on this website for a client: http://alsite2.stackinjb.com.au/. They want to add ‘skins’ or 'wings' to some pages, as you can see here: https://www.jbhifi.com.au/

If you look at the JB Hi Fi website, you’ll notice that when you scroll down, the top of the ad fixes to the top of the screen. On my site, I can’t seem to make this work.

Any help on how to make this work would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need some javascript for this. Every time the page is scrolling, you have to check the scroll position against the position of the sticky element. If the scroll position bigger than the position of the sticky element, make it sticky.

Check out [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/), this is a nice library for such things.